Intellij IDEA does not respond to Shift+Alt+F10 on Ubuntu 22.04
On Ubuntu 22.04 and Intellij IDEA 2024.2.1 I can't use shortcut "Shift + Alt + F10".
I can not even find the action registered to this shortcut (which is by default set to "Run..." action).
Find Shortcut window window does not recognize the shortcut and the field is empty when the keys combination is pressed. But it does recognize for example "Shift + Alt + F9" or "Shift + Alt + F11".
What might be the issue here?

There are two options to resolve the issue:

To re-map the action to a different shortcut which can be recognized by Intellij IDEA
Or, there is a system shortcut "Alt + F10" on Ubuntu 22.04 to maximize window, which stops passing it to the Intellij IDEA. Disable the system shortcut in Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcut settings and Intellij IDEA will recognize the shortcuts containing "Alt + F10" (also "Shift + Alt + F10") once again.

